# Save HTML as PDF (Tried Using MS Word, but embedded images failed!)

Tags: html, pdf, ms-word, save-as

I have an old program (15 years old?) that generates HTML attachments to emails.  Basically, contract details get attached, along with signatures.  The company wants to now send PDF attachments instead.

I tried to open the HTML attachments programmatically in MS Word, then SaveAs type 17 (PDF).  Issue is, my embedded background images -- those important signatures -- do not open in Word.

Any have any better ideas, or workarounds?

I tried to open HTML like this in Word:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE TYPE="TEXT/CSS">
.VERYSMALL {FONT-FAMILY:Arial; FONT-SIZE:7pt; FONT-WEIGHT:BOLD}
.SMALL {FONT-FAMILY:Arial; FONT-SIZE:8pt}
.REGULAR {FONT-FAMILY:Courier New; FONT-SIZE:10pt}
.HUGE {FONT-FAMILY:Courier New; FONT-SIZE:12pt; FONT-WEIGHT:BOLD}
@media print {
.no-print, .no-print * { display: none !important; } }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY class=REGULAR>
<TABLE width=660>
    <TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE border=0 width=660>
    <TR><TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
        &nbsp;
    </TD>
    <TD width=60% align=center class=HUGE>XYZ & CO., INC.
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
        &nbsp;
    </TD></TR>
    <TR><TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
        TELEPHONE
    </TD>
    <TD width=60% align=center class=SMALL>
        500 MAIN ST, NY  10001
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
        TELEX
    </TD></TR>
    <TR><TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
        (555) 555-5555
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=60%>
        &nbsp;
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
               
    </TD></TR>
    <TR><TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
        FAX
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=60% class=VERYSMALL>
        &nbsp;
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
               
    </TD></TR>
    <TR><TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
        (555) 555-5555
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=60% class=VERYSMALL>
        &nbsp;
    </TD>
    <TD align=center width=20% class=VERYSMALL>
               
    </TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<BR>

<TABLE width=660 class=REGULAR>
    <TR>
        <TD width=100>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD width=55>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD width=195>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD width=20>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD width=50>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD width=80>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD width=80>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD width=80>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan=2 valign=top align=Left>Contract Number:</TD>
        <TD valign=top>96549</TD>
        <TD valign=top align=Right colspan=2>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan=2 valign=top align=Left>Contract Date:</TD>
        <TD valign=top>October 12, 2022</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=5>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD align=left valign=top>SELLER:</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=7>ABC Co<BR>
A One Business Center<BR>
La Piece 3<BR>
1180 Rolle, Switzerland</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD align=left valign=top>BUYER:</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=7>XYZ and Co., Inc.<BR>
Main St<BR>
N.Y. 10001, USA</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <TR>
        <TD valign=top align=left>COMMODITY:</TD>
        <TD colspan=7>CRUDE PALM OIL, in bulk.  Malaysian/Indonesian origin at seller's option. </TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <TR>
        <TD valign=top align=left>QUANTITY:</TD>
        <TD colspan=7>250 Metric Tons</TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <TR>
        <TD valign=top align=left>SHIPMENT:</TD>
        <TD colspan=7>June, 2023</TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <TR>
        <TD valign=top align=left>PRICE:</TD>
        <TD colspan=7>USD 1022.50 per metric ton CIF Rotterdam</TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <TR>
        <TD valign=top align=left>ANALYSIS/ WEIGHTS:</TD>
        <TD colspan=7>Landed analysis and landed weights to govern.</TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <TR>
        <TD valign=top align=left>PAYMENT:</TD>
        <TD colspan=7>99% cash against documents on/before vessels arrival at port of destination, but not later than 45 days from Bill of Lading Date, unless documents are presented thereafter.  Balance to be settled on determination of landed weight and quality.</TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <TR>
        <TD valign=top align=left>SPECIAL CONDITIONS:</TD>
        <TD colspan=7>This contract is subject to the rules and regulations of FOSFA-80, including sticker AS-9 and in compliance with EU-1 regulations.<BR><BR>CIF Rotterdam Traceability terms.<BR><BR>FFA: Max 5% at time of shipment, basis 5% FFA on arrival. M&I basis pure on arrival.<BR><BR>OP #22101366</TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD colspan=8>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
</TABLE><BR>
<BR><TABLE width=660 class=REGULAR>
    <TR>
        <TD width=24>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=2 width=276>XYZ and Co., Inc.</TD>
        <TD width=24>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=2 width=276>ABC</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD width=24>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=2 width=276>(Buyer)</TD>
        <TD width=24>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD valign=top colspan=2 width=276>(Seller)</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan=6>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD width=24>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD valign=top width=24>By:</TD>
        <TD valign=bottom width=252 style="background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat"><BR><BR><BR><HR>(Signature)</TD>
        <TD valign=top width=24>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD valign=bottom width=252><BR><HR>(Signature)</TD>
        <TD valign=top width=24>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan=6>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE><BR></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your media line to match A4 output, it will resolve page size (note those margins for later).

`@media print { @page { margin: 0; size: 210mm 297mm ; } body { margin: 0; } }`

The browser settings should be default to image, open the `test.html` and print one with graphics on to check its working.

then in the folder at the console line run

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="%CD%\output.pdf" "%CD%\test.html"
```

Then type `output.pdf` and check the result, it should be up to the left.

[image]

there should be no visible header footer (because the margins obscure them)
Avoid adjusting that first value so I suggest for your case the second as `body { margin: 12mm; } }` should be about right (1/2"), too much will trip a new blank page, as seen here, by the page 1/2  :-

[image]

**For a full folders worth run**
***(NOTE if using a batchfile.bat change `%F` to `%%F` and the 2 x `%CD%\%~nF` edit to `%CD%\%%~nF`)***

```
for /f "usebackq delims==" %F in (`dir /b *.html`) do ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="%CD%\%~nF.pdf" "%CD%\%~nF.html")
```

[image]